# How dynamically use Decorator Pattern in Java and Spring

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data-jpa

(example driven explanation): I need to add and remove toppings for the pizzas available in runtime using the user interface.

How can I achieve this using SpringBoot and Spring Data SQL?

I know how to build a Decorator Pattern. However my question is how to do it in runtime.

Comment: Can you add some code for what you have tried? As it stands, the question is quite unclear.

Comment: @Thilo I have not written any code yet. I have read some examples in internet but all of them are hardcoding the construction of the pizza. 
How I do `new Pepperoni(new BasePizza());` in runtime? I don't know which topping is going to select the user.

Comment: In runtime you could do  things like `wantsPepperoni ? new Pepperoni(base) : base` or `new ExtraCheese(amountVariable, cheeseTypeEnumVariable, base)` or (`for (PizzaDecorator d: stackedDecorators){ pizza = d.decorate(pizza) } `

Comment: I get your point. Thanks.